# office script: loop error (reading 0) after first element

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I want to add a row after the cell that meets my condition per code below. However it returns error reading '0'.
After further checking I found that it can run the first element but returns an error after that.

My data is just demo data, with only one column: "abc1, acb2, acb3..."

Edit 1: When I test with setting a value at line `"B"+(i+1)`, the code works through the loop but still shows error reading '0'.

Edit 2: When I enable the `setvalue` line, it works. I don't know why this is the case.
Below is before and after.

[image]
[image]

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Your code here
  let mysheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let myrange = mysheet.getUsedRange().getValues() as string[][];
  //console.log(myrange[1][0]); (for test. worked)
  //mysheet.getRange("1:1").insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.down); (for test, worked)
  let count = 0 ;
  for (let i = 0;i<=myrange.length;i++){
    //console.log(myrange[i][0]); (for test, worked)
    if(myrange[i][0].indexOf("abc")>-1){
        //set value of right column when meet condition
        //mysheet.getRange("B"+ (i+1)).setValue("test"); (worked)

        //insert row at the row below when meet condition`
        mysheet.getRange((i+1)+":"+(i+1)).insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.down); //work for first element
        count++;
        //console.log(myrange);
        //break; (loop only work for first element with this "break" line
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you're looping through every instance that you find for the text that you're searching for, is that right?  Firstly, using `i+1` is going to screw with you given you're using that to add rows but you're injecting rows as you go, that would mean you need to reset your counter (sort of).  Secondly, show us screenshots of a before and after for the result.  That would help me solve your problem.

Comment: I've added the image at the edit.

Comment: So the image at the top is the before and the image at the bottom  is what you want the result to look like?

Comment: yes. and my code already work. but I don't know why it doesn't before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without know the absolute specifics of your requirement, using the test data you provided, have a go at this script.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let foundRangeArea = worksheet.findAll("abc", { completeMatch: false, matchCase: false });

    foundRangeArea.getAreas().reverse().forEach(range => {
        range.getCell(0,0).getOffsetRange(1,0).getEntireRow().insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.down);
    });
}
```

It turns this ...

[image: From]

... into this ...

[image: To]

Comment: thanks. your solution look very neat.

Comment: So if it worked for you, please flag it as the answer. Make the grey tick next to my answer green by clicking on it.

Comment: I'm sorry but my reputation not enough to mark an answer.